# Convert string yyyymmddhhmmss into hh:mm:ss format in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

With the string DATETIME `yyyymmddhhmmss` like `20160125173013`, I would like to convert this string into `hh:mm:ss (17:30:13)` as a new column called "Time" in a table with sql update statement. However I am only able to convert it into 17:30 using the stuff function. 
Is there any possible solution to convert?

In my statement

```
UPDATE db
SET Time =convert(time, stuff(substring(DATETIME,9,6),3,2,':'))
FROM db
WHERE Time IS NULL
```

Real Output=`17:13:00.0000000`

But my expected output is `17:13:00`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: mysql <> sql-server. Please don't tag products not involved

Comment: @HoneyBadger A lot of people confuse Microsoft SQL Server with a general "SQL server". The tag should be `sql`. I think we're all lucky Microsoft didn't call Windows "Operating System", as they nearly did that with DOS.

Comment: @tadman: Sql Server **is** Microsoft Sql Server. I agree they could have chosen a less generic name for the product, but never the less, an oracle server is not Sql server and mySql is also not Sql server.

Comment: @ZoharPeled MySQL is *a* SQL server, so is Postgres. It's not *the* SQL Server product. This is why new people get confused. They don't read the roll-over on the tags.

Comment: Actually, it's a database server, if you want to nitpick...

Comment: If it's a "SQL based database server" that's a "SQL server" for short, just like we have NoSQL servers too. Most DBA types avoid that term because it's a product name. This is also like "UNIX server" or "HTTP server".

Comment: Is this value stored / passed over as text or as a real datetime **typed** value? If it's typed the string which is presented to you, is not the actual value, but a textual representation of the value depending on system's settings... `17:30:00.0000` seems for to be quite the same as `17:30:00` (further more in your first line there are 13 seconds. Do you need this?

Comment: @tadman be that as it may, the SO tag [sql-server] refers to Microsoft SQL Server, not to a general sql based database sever. therefor, while your argument maybe valid, it's inapplicable in this case.

Comment: @ZoharPeled My "argument" is simply explaining why so many people mis-tag. Read what I'm saying. People also mistake `mysql` for "Mycrosoft SQL Server" for reasons I can't explain.

Comment: @tadman Well in that case I completely misunderstood you. sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the miracle for `mysql`:

```
SELECT time(str_to_date('20160125173013', '%Y%m%d%H%i%s'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ar eusing SQL server then use Convert function

```
 Declare  @VarCharDate  varchar(max)
 Declare  @VarCharDate1 varchar(max)
```

--Declare

```
set  @VarCharDate = '20160125173013' --- YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
```

--Convert

```
 set @VarCharDate1 =(select SUBSTRING(@VarCharDate,0,5) + '/' +
SUBSTRING(@VarCharDate,5,2)  + '/' + SUBSTRING(@VarCharDate,7,2)
  +  ' ' + SUBSTRING(@VarCharDate,9,2)
  +':'+SUBSTRING(@VarCharDate,11,2) +':' + RIGHT(@VarCharDate,2))

   select @VarCharDate1



 select  Convert(varchar(8),convert(datetime, @VarCharDate1, 120),114)
```

Comment: List of format you can directly in convert function are here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: This does not answer the question... The input string is not convertible directly. That's the challenge...

Comment: @Shnugo if you have a datetime column in the table and you want to cast it to hh:mi:ss then it should work . can you please tell me what exaclty not working . I will try to look in that . the answer I given is valid for valid datetime columns.

Comment: Well, the question clearly starts with *With the string DATETIME yyyymmddhhmmss like 20160125173013, I would like to convert this string into hh:mm:ss (17:30:13)*. Your answer is correct, but not addressing the actual issue...

Comment: sorry for that update my answer if still not got solution

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an actual `DATETIME` field? If so you can use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
UPDATE mytable SET my_time=DATE_FORMAT(my_date, '%H:%i:%s')
```

If you don't have a native `DATETIME` field I hope you can convert it to one, as irregular, quirky formats cause trouble and introduce a lot of overhead when parsing to convert. [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) can do the opposite of `DATE_FORMAT()` and convert from arbitrary strings to native `DATE` or `DATETIME` values.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse STORAGE with PRESENTATION

```
Declare @YourTable table (DateTime varchar(25),Time time)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('20160125173013',null)

Update @YourTable
   Set Time = stuff(left(right(DateTime,6),4),3,0,':')

Select * 
      ,FormatedTime = Format(cast(Time as datetime),'HH:mm')
 From @YourTable
```

Returns

```
DateTime        Time                FormatedTime
20160125173013  17:30:00.0000000    17:30
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the use of the `STUFF` function I believe this is Microsoft SQL Server, and not MySql. 
Therefor, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE db
SET [Time] = CAST(SUBSTRING([DATETIME], 9, 2) +':'+ 
                  SUBSTRING([DATETIME], 11, 2) +':'+ 
                  RIGHT([DATETIME], 2) As Time)
WHERE [Time] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string is no format, SQL Server will cast implicitly

```
DECLARE @YourDateTimeString VARCHAR(100)='20160125173013';
```

The following query will cut the first 8 digits and cast them to `DATE`, which works implicitly (unseparated format). The time is cut from the right side, then the two `:`-signs are stuffed into the right places:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(@YourDateTimeString,8) AS DATE)
      ,CAST(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(@YourDateTimeString,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') AS TIME);
```

The result

```
2016-01-25  17:30:13.0000000
```

If you need this as string without the trailing `.0000000` (**which is a pure output format question and should be done in your presentation layer!**) you can just use `LEFT()`. The input of this function is string (again implicitly casted), the output is **a text which *looks* like a time**.

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(@YourDateTimeString,8) AS DATE)
      ,LEFT(CAST(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(@YourDateTimeString,6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') AS TIME),8);
```

The result

```
2016-01-25  17:30:13
```